# publishing Db after creating using EF Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, nuget

I have created a project in MVC 3  using code first and nugget ,
 And I would like to clear a few thing before publishing to my shared hosting:
In my project I have a class name: `IchudShulContext` (`IchudShul` is my project name)
In my sql server express it has created a DB name: `IchudShul.Models.IchudShulContext.dbo`
Does it make a different what name I give my shared hosting DB ?
Or should it match one of the following : `IchudShul` / `IchudShulContext`
My local connectionStrings look like this :

```
connectionString="Data Source=MyPc-MAINPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IchudShul.Models.IchudShulContext;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Code-First convention, Your **ConnectionString name** in your web.config should have the same name as your context. Database name is not important. in your scenario, in your web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="IchudShulContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    connectionString="Data Source=MyPc-MAINPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WHATEVER_YOUR_DB_NAME_IS;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If you want to use conventions, make sure the **name** attribute is: `IchudShulContext`. That's all. Fill in `WHATEVER_YOUR_DB_NAME_IS` with whatever you db name is.

Answer (score 0):

Your shared hosting DB can be named anything.

Your ConnectionString should be updated needs to be updated to point to your database. What that is, you will need to know from your shared hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

you can name you DB anything, as long as it is valid with respect to your DBMS. the only this that should be matched with your datacontext name is connection name in connection strings section of your web.config file.